# Laravel paginator in custom query

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

I am working on a project in laravel.
I have sql queries as string in db. The queries are very important.
There is no way to write them in laravel relationships because of some situation
so

**DB::select($table->query) I wanna paginate this with laravel paginate.**

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Query Builder also implements the `paginate()` method:

```
DB::table($table->query)->paginate(15);
```

Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) on this subject for further information.

Comment: Asur your solution not works. I found a way to do this. I get all ids from query,  then make array of this ids,  then Table::whereIn('id', $array)->paginate(15) this works. Thanks

Comment: @OzalZarbaliyev I'm sorry but your question then was not clear enough, I can't find anything related to `whereIn` in your post, you asked just for a pagination method using the Laravel Query builder.

Comment: @OzalZarbaliyev It doesn't really matter but in the future try to be more specific in your questions :)

Comment: i did know ->paginate(15), before i asked question I tried paginate it it simple and first step :) That's why I said custom query from db which can be any query.

Comment: @OzalZarbaliyev What I mean is that your question has no information at all apart from the pagination part

Comment: paginate not works with custom queries. gives Call to a member function paginate() on array.

Comment: @OzalZarbaliyev https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results